# Subtract two times of different dates in mysql

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

How do i subtract two times which are in two different dates, say
23:20:45  of 2019/07/24
00:10:32 of 2019/07/25

I have to note the duration of people which log into the system at night, but as the date changes it's a bit difficult to do so
I need a mysql query which will return me the exact time in hours:minutes:seconds.

Comment: What is the datatype of your column ? Is it varchar or datetime ?

Comment: it's varchar @Madhur Bhaiya

Comment: So, the value is stored as this: `23:20:45 of 2019/07/24` OR `23:20:45 2019/07/24`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [TIMEDIFF() function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timediff):

```
SELECT TIMEDIFF('2019-07-25 00:10:32', '2019-07-24 23:20:45')
```

will return `'00:49:47'`.

But note that the maximum time difference that can be returned is `838:59:59`.

Comment: `STR_TO_DATE(column, '%T %Y/%m/%d')` is needed before TimeDiff. Check the comment under the question

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya You are right. Feel free to post the full answer. (right now) I'm tired of improper data type usage and of asking for clarification.